# How to do proportional editing and keeping wall thickness?

Tags: edit-mode, proportional-editing

I've got an object to edit, figured out how to proportional edit it, but now its wall thickness is ruined. How to address this issue?

As the image shows, the inner and the outer surface of the wall of the edited hull got far away from each other (The top part of the hull is being hidden).

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Please add some images to illustrate the issue. There could be many reasons for this.

Comment: Hello! :) I have updated the question, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Your mesh is very dense and your topology is triangles instead of quads. This will make it harder to control your mesh no matter what tool you use. If you keep it quads, you can easily select edge and face loops, to facilitate tweaking the form. Also, keeping the mesh low poly, and only adding geometry where needed to establish the vital form, will help allow you to change the overall shape without things getting out of control. Proportional editing can help get some control back over very dense forms. But it's still better to keep things as light as possible.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why not use proportional editing on both outer and inner wall at once?

Comment: ..or you _might_ be able to delete the inner skin, and use a Solidify modifier instead, that would depend on sharp concave areas, and whether you're looking for a constant wall thickness.